# How to reflect sheet1's those rows only which contains positive values, into sheet2?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

My question is this-
If there is any positive value in sheet1’s cell no k5 then the entire 5th row’s all values should be reflected in sheet2’s row 5th. Similarly if there is any positive value in k6 then the entire 6th row’s all values should be reflected into sheet2’s row 6th. If there is positive value in k5 and negative value in k6 and again positive value in k7 then, 7th row of sheet1 should be reflected in sheet2’s 6th row (means it should skip the rows containing negative values from sheet1). Please look at these snapshots for better understanding-
[http://imgur.com/a/sxVIc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlMZf.png)

I want any formula for sheet2 in which i can show the positive values of sheet1 only. So i want a formula for k5 to k100 in sheet2. please provide me any formula which can solve my purpose.

THANKS A LOT

Comment: i would use countif to find negative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *Sheet2* cell **A5** enter:

```
=IF(Sheet1!$K5>0,Sheet1!A5,"")
```

copy this cell both across and downwards

Comment: Thank you very much dear Gary's Student..the formula suggested by you is good but there is a problem in it. As if there is negative values in row 6 in sheet1 then it shows sheet2's row 6 to be blank. while i want it should show the next row containing positive values of sheet1 in row 6 of sheet2. I mean to say there should not be any blank row in sheet2 and it should show all positive rows of sheet1 continuously into sheet2. Please look at this snapshoot-                                                                             http://imgur.com/R00joZM